# Continue script if external copying is done Powershell

Tags: powershell

When a test folder is changed on my desktop, a script will do something.

**For example**
If I copy some folders with subfolders to my test folder. I imagine that the script waits until external copying will be done and after that the script will continue.

This script is watcher for my folder.

```
#<Set Path to be monitored>#
$searchPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\test" 

#<Set Watch routine>#
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $searchPath
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

#<Set Events>#
$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action {
   Write-EventLog Application -source Powershell -EventId 54321 -Message "Application will be update"
   write-host "Application will be update $($eventArgs.FullPath)"

 #something what will be wait until copying will 
 done and after that will script continue

   Start-Process powershell -argument '.\done.ps1'
  }

while ($true){ sleep 2}
#<END_SCRIPT>#
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach as it is difficult to determine when the copying is fully done. e.g. The last file might be very large and take much longer to appear then the rest...  
Instead, if you have control over the copying process, I would look to the process (rather then the files) and wait till it is done: `Start-Process -Wait ...`

Comment: This is bad for a number of reasons.  If you're watching for changes to a folder and trying to catch a programmatic copy, then the suggestion iRon present could work--wait for the process owning the copy to complete.  If users are copying an undefined number of files, then your filesystemwatcher can only act upon when each file is "created" since that's the event you're hooking.  Also, the scriptblock you're defining only has access to the single "created" event data.  It can't wait for the rest of the copy process in the context of the single event...